# Running a user defined function in a SELECT statement - MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, select

I have a simple table called `unzip`. It has three columns as follows -: `id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, `share_src VARCHAR(30) NULL`, `creator INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`.

I also have a function called `checkSrc` which returns `no` or `yes` when a share_src is provided to it as a parameter.

I want to return all the rows where creator is `10` AND (`share_src is null` or 
`the result from the function checkSrc is yes`).

Currently i am doing this

```
SELECT * FROM unzip WHERE creator = 12 AND (share_src IS NULL || checkSrc(share_src) = 'yes');
```

But this results in an error. Whats the problem in the query? A lot thanks for help..

Comment: What is parameter type function expecting?

Comment: The parameter type is int

Comment: And what is col type for share_src? Also what is return type? What is error?

Comment: Oh! Thanks @AshReva, i got it. Share_src is VARCHAR and the parameter expected is INT. Thanks a lot

Comment: its nice to accept answers to show your appreciation. I have updated answer from my comments. Hope you are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM unzip WHERE creator = 12 AND (share_src IS NULL Or checkSrc(share_src) = 'yes');

Try and let me know.

Check if function is returning correct data type. Check if its returning string type.